# Work assignment rebus puzzle

Tags: visual, rebus

[image]

confuse about the rebus if its 
yolk or egg + sun or drawing+ sill? if thats whats called
loves
the world \universe + square and well

Answer (score 9):

I think it's something like:

> Yggdrasil loves the Urd Squirrel

From

> Egg+draw+sill loves the earth square+well.

This references

> Norse mythology, specifically the tree Yggdrasil, the well Urd, and the squirrel Ratatosk.

I'm a little skeptical of my answer because:

> I used 'well' to form 'squirrel' = square+well, but Urd (from 'Earth') is an actual well, making me question my wordplay. Maybe a coincidence.

Comment: i guessed yggdrasil loves the norse universe?

Comment: I don’t think that’s the answer because in Norse Mythology, Ratatosk, the squirrel is trying to destroy Yggdrasil.